# How can I identify these data types

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the data type for a dataset in Postgres. What data type is:

- country name, eg. Nigeria, Finland, etc.
- decimals, eg. 7.3, 9.4, etc
- whole numbers, eg. 2341, 8892, etc.

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype.html) explains data types.

Comment: Varchar float int

Answer (score 0):

Country name will be varchar(n) or char(n).
Decimals will be float(n).
Whole numbers will be int or one of its variations.

You need to define the maximum size of your data: how many characters are needed for the longest names? What are the biggest numbers that could need to be stored?

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)